# Get a couchDB document with a external parameter

Tags: javascript, rest, view, dictionary, couchdb

I have a couchDB database with different documents. I need to use them on my web application, so when the user puts some word on the app, I would get that document from the DB.
This is my _desing document

```
{
   "_id": "_design/recuperar",
   "_rev": "3-6787751eb0ed728b482ef7b06658e8da",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "grafos": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n    var value;\n    if (doc.nome== 'Egypt') {         \n            value = [doc.nodos, doc.links];\n            emit(doc.nome, value);       \n    }\n}"
       }
   }
}
```

And it works, but what I want is that 'Egypt' would be a variable with the content of the user's search. Is that possible?? Or will I have to do a different view for each search/document???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the user search parameter after the query .../?user_search=foo and then access the var user_search from within your view, does it make sense? You can check here for more extensive info: 
http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List

Comment: Mmmm. First of all thanks for the answer !! :)  Now I need to check it, 'cause I'm doing all this from another server, in a javascript document, where with the name of the db and the view I can have the info.  So I don't ask for the query that way...  I need to give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this condition from your view `if (doc.nome== 'Egypt')` and use the [query API](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API#Querying_Options) in the standard way: `?key='Egypt'`

Comment: I can't use it in the standard way, 'cause I'm asking from a javascript page in a different port, and I have a cross domain issue. But I can consult a design document or a view...  Till the moment it's all I was been able to do.  But thanks, any way  :)